# passport-facebook strategy callback function never gets called

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am a newbie in passport , here i am trying to use passport-facebook strategy for authentication.
But the callback function defined inside "FacebookStrategy" never gets called means "Facebook callback called" never gets printed on console.
Although the success case runs everytime.

Here is my code

```
// Initialising passport
router.use(passport.initialize());

//router.use(passport.session()); /*I don't want to use passport session*/

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

/**
 *  Configuring FacebookStrategy
 */
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'facebook_client_id', // Facebook Client ID
    clientSecret: 'facebook_client_secret', // Facebook Client Secret
    callbackURL: 'https://sheltered-earth-74671.herokuapp.com/signin/facebook/callback' // Callback URL after user allow information access
}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) { // Callback Function

    console.log('Facebook callback called'); /*THIS ISN'T PRINTING*/

    done(null, profile);
}));

router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email']
}));

router.get('/facebook/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(req.query.code);  // This is working
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation suggests:

Update the callback function as:

```
router.get('/facebook/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', 
    { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }
));
```

[See more here.](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/facebook/)

Comment: This did the job but can you tell me why is this important to call the function.

Comment: Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise, authentication has failed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me.